# NTFS permissionless for limited user account xp home

Tags: windows-xp, ntfs

Help me please...
How to make every external drive with NTFS enable delete files or folder in limited user account xp home edition. Just like automaticaly permissionless. Like FAT32. 
I can make it in one drive (ex, my ext drive), but if any other drive inserted, system can't do automatically. The simple question is, how to make NTFS just like FAT32..

Comment: Can't you just format it with fat32?

Comment: @MattH, NTFS has several advantages, including journaling and support for files larger than 4 GB.  The OP simply wants to disable the security features of NTFS so that any user has complete control over the contents of the device.

Answer (score 2):

Start using a hard drive image software to "ghost" a copy of the entire drive, that way you can wipe the computers in a few clicks and give a like new machine to your next customer.  And they can be admins and use it however they like!

Ultimately they have physical access which means you cannot guarantee they do not bypass the restriction somehow... so why bother?

I like and use Acronis True Image, the boot disk option is totally overpowered too -- I don't make use of the automated bloatware.  Point and click software... even a dumby like me can use it without a manual.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't.

Each file on a drive that is formatted with NTFS will have an ACL that determines who is allowed access and what they are allowed to do.

Each external drive formatted gives only the admins delete permission.  You'll need to start at the root of the external drive, change the permissions under the Security tab and then let the changes propagate to all the files and folders.

<s>An easier way to do this is to use the tool `icacls`.</s>

`icacls e:\ /grant Mycomputer\Users:(OI)(CI) M /t`

#### Edit:

For XP, Download [Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18546)

Then use `xcacls e:\ /e /c /t /p:Users:RC /y`.

Comment: Would icacls be available in Windows XP?

Comment: oops, you'd use Calcs in XP.  I'll change that.

Comment: The condition is like this: i have computers for rent here.. And inside the computers there are much multimedia file that users who rent my computer need to download or copy to their external hard drive. Because of this for public, I made limited user in XP Home ed. So, users have no permission or privilege to modify their external drive.. (sory for my bad english, becouse i'm not english) thanks alot..